# Swarms and Targeted Spells

Tags: dnd-5e, swarm

Last night, I had a Swarm of Bats sharing a space with one of my PCs, and two of the others used spells against it: Fire Bolt and Poison Spray.  The question came up asking if it would affect the PC sharing the space with the swarm.  At the time, I ruled `no`, since they're not area affects, and I default to permissive during play so I can spend the time researching rules after.

However, I can't find any sources on what happens in this situation.  It seems to make sense that at least Poison Spray would affect the swarmed PC, but I can't find any sources one way or another.  Is there anything definitive anywhere?  If not, it seems like, RAW, it wouldn't, since, again, not area effects.